# How are curl, git, or heroku able to run from the command line regardless of the current file path?

Tags: git, curl, heroku

How are they able to get git, curl, or heroku to run from anywhere. For example, just by runnning:

```
$curl
```

or

```
$git
```

or

```
$heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell will look in all directories listed in your `PATH`.

To check your path type:

```
echo $PATH            # Print the path on screen
```

To find which directory a command was found in, use `which` (on Linux type systems):

```
which curl
```